# Singleton alternative for PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is my class that I'm using to connect to my `MySQL` database.
As you can see I'm using the `Singleton Pattern` but almost every post says it is a very bad pattern. What is the best approach to create a database connection class? Is there a better pattern?

```
class DB extends PDO {

    function __construct() {
        try {
            parent::__construct('mysql:host=' . 'localhost' . ';dbname=' . 'kida', 'root', 'root', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
            parent::setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public static function get_instance() {
        static $instance = false;
        if(!$instance) $instance = new self;
        return $instance; //returns pdo object.
     }
}
```

Comment: Have you compared what you're doing to how an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or
[Propel](http://propelorm.org/) does it?

Comment: @Marcus: it's a static var. you the `= false` bit is executed only ONCE

Comment: Saying a pattern is bad/good is purely an opinion. Some opinions are better than others (e.g. "murder is bad"), but still remains an opinion. If a pattern works for you in your particular case, then so be it. If you find yourself using a lot of "bad" patterns, then maybe you should re-evaluate your design, but there's no hard/fast 100% accurate good/bad rating on these sorts of things.

Comment: A good read: [Building an abstraction class on a user-friendly raw-API like PDO is, IMHO, like a broken pencil: Pointless](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/29394/27767)

Comment: I understand your point. So what do you suggest for me? @MarcB

Comment: So I should not extend the PDO class right? @JimL

Comment: Imho (it's very opiniated) it's not needed. I've spent quite some time with PDO, a company who had a PDO wrapper, and with Doctrine. I felt most comfortable either with the standard PDO class, or with the full fledged Doctrine 2 ORM.

Comment: So if I decide to go with pure PDO I need to create a new PDO in all my queries right? I do not want to use globals? What do you suggest? @JimL

Comment: No in a normal request you'd only create one PDO instance (you can run multiple queries on the same connection). If your queries are in classes or functions you'd probably want to inject the database connection into said classes or functions.

Comment: Can you explain it further I do not have much experience in PDO. Yes my queries are in methods inside classes. How can I inject the connection to them? global? @JimL

Comment: Just pass it into wherever you need it. `$db = new PDO... function findUser($db, $id){ $db->query('get user by id'); }`

Comment: yes but how should I include `$db = new PDO...` ? create a new one in each class? @JimL

Comment: It depends on your application structure. Many request/response style apps (like Symfony) use a front end controller that all request are sent to where they set up (bootstrap) the application and route the request to whichever code should run. Either way it's just to find a starting point for the request, set up the db connection and instantiate the classes injecting whatever you need into them. It's called dependency injection, a topic well worth a read.

Comment: I put together an example here, it's probably not working (it at least needs an autoloader), and definetely riddled with flaws. But it at least shows the concept. The controller being the code that is supposed to execute on that request http://pastebin.com/qTqWNUGf

Comment: So we load `PDO $db` from an external `db.php` file? @JimL

Comment: You could, it makes sense if the users request different php files so you don't have to repeat code across these files. Optionally you could as mentioned route all requests to a single php file that  bootstraps your app (getting config, logging, db connetion, etc) and fires up the appropriate code for the requested resource.

Comment: I have a php.ini file that i include everywhere should i add there? @JimL

Comment: There is no definitive right or wrong way to it. Without seeing the application it's hard to give definitive suggestions as to how to structure the code and how the code should "flow" through the application. I suggest you just make it work, if you ever feel you're writing the same code over and over again, think about how you can change the code or the structure of your application to split things apart and include/extend stuff in order to not duplicate code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the singleton-pattern (or antipattern) is considered bad practice because it makes testing your code very hard and the depencies very convoluted until the project becomes hard to manage at some point. You can only have one fixed instance of your object per php-process. When writing automated unit-tests for your code you need to be able to replace the object the code you want to test uses with a test-double that behaves in a prdictable manner. When the code you want to test uses a singleton, then you cannot replace that with a test double.

The best way (to my knowlege) to organize the interaction between objects (like your Database-Object and other objects using the database) would be to reverse the direction of the depencies. That means that your code is not requesting the object it needs from an external source (in most cases a global one like the static 'get_instance' method from your code) but instead gets its depency-object (the one it needs) served from outside before it needs it. Normally you would use a Depency-Injection Manager/Container like [this one from the symfony project](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html#basic-usage) to compose your objects.

Objects that use the database-object would get it injected upon construction. It can be injected either by a setter method or in the constructor. In most cases (not all) is it better to inject the depency (your db-object) in the constructor because that way the object that uses the db-object will never be in an invalid state.

Example:

```
interface DatabaseInterface
{
    function query($statement, array $parameters = array());
}

interface UserLoaderInterface
{
    public function loadUser($userId);
}

class DB extends PDO implements DatabaseInterface
{
    function __construct(
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=kida',
        $username = 'root',
        $password = 'root',
    ) {
        try {
            parent::__construct($dsn, $username, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
            parent::setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    function query($statement, array $parameters = array())
    {
        # ...
    }
}

class SomeFileBasedDB implements DatabaseInterface
{
    function __construct($filepath)
    {
        # ...
    }

    function query($statement, array $parameters = array())
    {
        # ...
    }
}

class UserLoader implements UserLoaderInterface
{
    protected $db;

    public function __construct(DatabaseInterface $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function loadUser($userId)
    {
        $row = $this->db->query("SELECT name, email FROM users WHERE id=?", [$userId]);

        $user = new User();
        $user->setName($row[0]);
        $user->setEmail($row[1]);

        return $user;
    }
}

# the following would be replaced by whatever DI software you use,
# but a simple array can show the concept.


# load this from a config file
$parameters = array();
$parameters['dsn'] = "mysql:host=my_db_server.com;dbname=kida_production";
$parameters['db_user'] = "mydbuser";
$parameters['db_pass'] = "mydbpassword";
$parameters['file_db_path'] = "/some/path/to/file.db";


# this will be set up in a seperate file to define how the objects are composed
# (in symfony, these are called 'services' and this would be defined in a 'services.xml' file)
$container = array();
$container['db'] = new DB($parameters['dsn'], $parameters['db_user'], $parameters['db_pass']);
$container['fileDb'] = new SomeFileBasedDB($parameters['file_db_path']);

# the same class (UserLoader) can now load it's users from different sources without having to know about it.
$container['userLoader'] = new UserLoader($container['db']);
# or: $container['userLoader'] = new UserLoader($container['fileDb']);

# you can easily change the behaviour of your objects by wrapping them into proxy objects.
# (In symfony this is called 'decorator-pattern')
$container['userLoader'] = new SomeUserLoaderProxy($container['userLoader'], $container['db']);

# here you can choose which user-loader is used by the user-controller
$container['userController'] = new UserController($container['fileUserLoader'], $container['viewRenderer']);
```

Notice how the different classes no not know about each other. There are no direct depencies between them. This is done by not require the actual class in the constructor, but instead require the interface that provides the methods it needs.

That way you can always write replacements for your classes and just replace them in the depency-injection container. You do not have to check the whole codebase because the replacement just has to implement the same interface that is used by all other classes. You know that everything will continue to work because every component using the old class only knows about the interface and calls only methods known by the interface.

P.S.: Please excuse my constant references to the symfony project, it is just what i am most used to. Other project's like Drupal, Propel or Zend probably also have concepts like this.

Comment: Sorry, this ex. is confusing me. Never used any of these frameworks in PHP? is there  a simple ex. in pure php. or the main idea for ex.?  @Gerrit

Comment: The main idea is that you are providing all objects (like the db-object) to other objects that use them from outside. Instead of looking from the inside and getting the db when you need it you look from the outside and 'give' the db to other objects (like in the constructor).

Comment: The example-code from my answer is pure php by the way. The other classes i referenced are just for the idea and do not actually exist.